# how can i decrypt huawei HG531s v1 config file?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, firmware, encryption, python

[I have tried to follow this guide](https://hg658c.wordpress.com/2017/12/04/decrypting-configuration-files-from-other-huawei-home-gateway-routers/) but 
libxmlapi.so didn't have the required ATP_GetInfo1 function
so i moved to the next file libhttpapi.so 
it had

```
ATP_GetInfo1
ATP_GetInfo2 
ATP_GetInfo3 
ATP_GetInfo4
```

so i copied the first two .

then ATP_GetInfo3 from libcfmapi.so file

then ATP_GetInfo4 from libmsgapi.so file
.... and when i tried to run the script [decode_keystore.py](https://pastebin.com/zJechi09) but it gave me

> ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length

.... and i think because the values wasn't in the same length

[The firmware file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4x8y97j256uvd04/hg531s1.BIN/file)

Comment: Make sure your strings are 240 characters in length.

Comment: @Madushan how while there are not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mailed [Nirsoft RouterPassView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/router_password_recovery.html) tool creator for about a month and he figured the way to decrypt it after so many tries ... and it wasn't the way that you mentioned in the article at all but it was in one of the mentioned files `libcfmapi.so`

and finally when he figured it out he said

> It's from the strings I found, but I had to put them in different
> order: (look in the colored chars):
> [image]

the order he used was for the key you take one character from all the first four strings then the second then third till the end of these stings after the equal mark and repeat and for the IV you did the same for the last four strings
so it results into this

> IV: F64D19C622D7C01176C3F02E0E941F31
>
> Key (AES128) : B5662E0C6DEC255FD25A159A6CB3E454